# How does auto-correlation work and how can I use it in matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I would like to know how auto-correlation works. How can I find peaks in the signal after applying an auto-correlation function on a signal in Matlab?

Answer (score 4):

Read the Matlab documentation on [auto-correlation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/econ/autocorr.html).